# Is there any characterisation of problems solvable in $n^2$ time

Tags: time-complexity, polynomial-time

Basically I am asking if we know necessary and sufficient conditions for a problem to be solvable in, for example, $n^2$ time. Or if not, if there are any theorems on whether or not a broad class of problems can be solved in $n^2$.

Comment: Are you interested in problems which can be solved in $O(n^2)$ time, or in problems which require $\Omega(n^2)$ time?

Comment: I do not know if it even makes sense what I am trying to ask. Basically, if there are theorems that give lower bounds to time complexities for a broader set of problems, like, for example how Savitch might help find the space complexity even without finding an algorithm for that particular problem

Comment: A broad but trivial class of problems requiring $\Omega(n^2)$ time is when you are asked to output some feature on all pairs of elements.

Comment: You might want to look into fine-grained complexity theory, for example 3SUM-hardness. While these offer lower bounds only conditioned on some conjectures (i.e. conditional lower bounds), they still give you a sense of what might require, say, essentially quadratic time given the current state of our knowledge. To the best of my knowledge, there is no natural decision problem in NP for which we can prove a quadratic lower bound unconditionaly in a relatively realistic model of computation (word-RAM for example, or random access Turing machines)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look